# Altair: How to add labels to bar charts that have rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, altair

When trying to add labels to an Altair bar chart which has rows, I get an SchemaValidationError. I'm talking about labels like here:
https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/bar_chart_with_labels.html

And I'm talking about bar charts with rows or "horizontal grouped bar charts" like this:
https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart_horizontal.html

Here is the code that does NOT work:

```
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='sum(yield):Q',
    y='year:O',
    row='variety:N',
)
bars

text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=3  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
).encode(
    text='sum(yield):Q'
)

bars + text
```

If I remove the row option in the bar chart it works as expected:

```
bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='sum(yield):Q',
    y='year:O'
)
bars

text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=3  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
).encode(
    text='sum(yield):Q'
)

bars + text
```

Adding the rows to the 'mark_text' method also does not help...

In the end I'd like to see labels to the right of my bars like indicated here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/23eHN.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error from your code snippet is

```
ValueError: Faceted charts cannot be layered.
```

In general, there is no guarantee that two faceted charts will have matching facets that are able to be layered, so Vega-Lite does not allow faceted charts to be layered.

The way to get around this is to facet a layered chart rather than layer a faceted chart. For example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='sum(yield):Q',
    y='year:O',
)
bars

text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=3  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
).encode(
    text='sum(yield):Q'
)

(bars + text).facet(row='variety:N')
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast. Your code does not work :(. I still get the same error which I already reported.

Comment: Make certain you are using Altair version 3.1 or newer. In older versions, the data has to be specified differently.

Comment: If for some reason you can't use the latest version of Altair, then delete ``source`` as an argument of ``alt.Chart()`` and instead put it as an argument of facet: ``facet(row='variety:N', data=source)``.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Using altair 3.1 it works :)

Comment: If you wanted to sort the above chart by the sum of yield during 1931, so that the order of the rows would be Trebi, Wisconsin N. 38, No. 457, how would you do that?